# How to use 2 tables in Recursive SQL query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Need help on recursive query

Table 1

```
ID
4
3079
```

Table 2

```
Source, Target
5,     4
6,     5
3080,  3079
3081,  3080
```

Result would be

```
ID  Result column
4,  4
4,  5
4,  6
3079,3079
3079,3080
3079,3081
```

First table ID column should start recursive from second table Target column and bring source value and again put it in target column

this is looping kind of sql query

kindly help on this

Need CTE recursive type SQL Query
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OTgL.png)

Comment: you can refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) on recursive query

Comment: Based on your example, you can do that with with a union between an inner join and an outer join of your source and target, no recursion needed. If your data is more complex than that, maybe elaborate your example data.

Answer (score 0):

```
with rec(root, source, target) as (
  select t1.id, t2.source, t2.target 
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.target = t1.id
  union all 
  select rec.root, t2. source, t2.target 
  from rec join table2 t2 on rec.source = t2.target 
)
select root, source as source_target from rec order by root, source
```

This query returns:

```
root    source_target
4       5
4       6
3079    3080
3079    3081
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xZMsiWNw)

If you need also rows 4, 4 and 3079, 3079 then union result with table1 ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pvyocQDp)).

```
... union all 
select id, id from table1 where id in (select target from table2)
order by root, source
```